# Event firing multiple times inside the same template

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have this "comment" template:

```
<template name="comment">
  <li class="comment" id="{{_id}}" >

    <div class="comment-wrapper level-{{level}}-comment">
      <span id="reply-btn" class="reply-btn reply-btn-{{_id}}"><a href="#">reply</a></span>
      <div class="content">
        <p>{{body}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="reply-to-comment reply-to-comment-{{_id}}" style="display:none;">
      <form name="reply" class="reply-form">
          <label for="reply_body">Reply to this comment</label>
          <textarea name="reply_body"></textarea>
          <button type="submit" class="btn">Post reply</button>
      </form>
    </div>

    {{#if showChildComments}}
      <ul class="comment-children comment-list">
        {{#each childComments}}
          {{> comment this}}
        {{/each}}
      </ul>
    {{/if}}

  </li>
</template>
```

With this comment.js file associated (only showing the events part here):

```
Template.comment.events({
  "click #reply-btn": function(e, template){
    console.log("Got in.")
    $(".reply-to-comment-"+template.data._id).toggle();
  }
});
```

Now, everytime I click reply it should open the reply form for that specific comment, as placed by the template above.

This works, but only on the "root" comments, meaning: if I click reply on a reply that is a reply to a "root" comment, the `console.log("Got in.")` will trigger 3 times. If it's a 5 level deep reply it will trigger 5 times, etc.

I suspect the reason for this is the fact that I'm rendering the template "comment" inside the template "comment". As such there's many "events" for which meteor is listening...

But I don't see how I could do it any other way. So, anyone knows a fix for this issue, or a better way to achieve what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct - the nested template is registering the event multiple times on those elements causing the issue.  I think you can use `event.stopPropagation()` to stop the event from bubbling up.

Answer (score 1):

It might be something different, but all your comments have `span#reply-btn`.

> The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the id attribute value must be unique within the HTML document).
>
> The id attribute can be used to point to a style in a style sheet.
>
> The id attribute can also be used by a JavaScript (via the HTML DOM) to make changes to the HTML element with the specific id.

Behaviour of elements with same id is not well-defined and may lead to problems like this.

Comment: Would make sense, but I changed the event to `"click #reply-btn"` and the same thing happens.

Comment: But it's still the same. Remove id from `span#reply-button` and change `click #reply-btn` to `click .reply-btn` (it already have that class).

Comment: Oh yea I meant to type `"click .reply-btn"`. Sorry for the confusion. The next answer fixed my issue. Thanks for your help though!